# Ruby on Rails Devise, how to change signin path when authentication fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, routes, devise

I have recently implemented Devise into my new app, in conjunction with Omniauth, however I am unsure how to change the default signin path in Devise so that when I call:

```
user_authenticated!
```

It will redirect to the authentication controller page.
Any ideas how to do this?

EDIT: To better explain my problem ->

What I want is when a user tries to access a page that requires you to be logged in and then gets sent to users/sign_in by the user_authenticated before filter, however I want them to be redirected to `/auth` via `user_authenticated!` not users/sign_in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```
before_filter do
  authenticate_user! rescue redirect_to auth_url
end
```

Comment: This is kind of the closest thing that has got something working for me now, simply redirecting if a user is not logged in so !current_user instead of authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I really understood your problem, but to redirect to a particular page this should be the implementation

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
  end
end
```

if you want to have another url for the sign_in process, in your routes.rb

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  end
```

and everything else you need at
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki

hope it's useful

Comment: From what I wrote I can see why you posted this, this will solve another issue I had however but what I want is when a user tries to access a page that requires you to be logged in and then gets sent to users/sign_in but I want them to be sent to /auth the user_authenticated! is a before_filter.